# angular 8 chips autocomplete on bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, tags, angular8, ngx-chips

Is there any type of similar version of the chips autocomplete for angular 8 and bootstrap like there is for  the last example in angular material in here: https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview ?

I would like to have the possibility to invite users by existent user or by email like there is in gitlab (see bellow):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use PrimeNG chips.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chips

Possible to use with Model Driven Forms. A chip is customized using a ng-template element where the value is passed as the implicit variable.